# How to deploy pipelines on user demand in AWS app

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker, pipeline

I am currently looking at the possibility to use AWS as a way to scale up the infrastructure. I am looking for the best way to set up an application to run different computational pipelines with data provided by the user. I have already seen the possibility of creating on-demand cluster using containers to run the analysis that are currently available (already predefined and ready in containers).

I am looking for advices in which are the amazon services tipically used to launch computations (or containers) once they have been selected in a web app by a user and stored in the backend.
Thanks

Comment: There is no simple solution for this in AWS, you can use iron.io workers or Auth0 WebTasks for this purpose. Or write you custom solution on top of Docker.